# how to use TFTP ( Trivial File Transfer Protocol )?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tftp

How to use TFTP ( Trivial File Transfer Protocol ) and i need to transfer a file using TFTP  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this](http://www.davidsudjiman.info/2006/03/27/installing-and-setting-tftpd-in-ubuntu/) useful.

Excerpt:

> 1. Install tftpd and related packages.
>      `$ sudo apt-get install xinetd tftpd tftp`
> 2. Create `/etc/xinetd.d/tftp` and put this entry:
>      service tftp
>      {
>      protocol        = udp
>      port            = 69
>      socket_type     = dgram
>      wait            = yes
>      user            = nobody
>      server          = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
>      server_args     = /tftpboot
>      disable         = no
>      }
> 3. Make /tftpboot directory
>      `$ sudo mkdir /tftpboot`
>      `$ sudo chmod -R 777 /tftpboot`
>      `$ sudo chown -R nobody /tftpboot`
> 4. Start tftpd through xinetd
>      `$ sudo /etc/init.d/xinetd start`

Answer (score 1):

See this article:
[Quick HOWTO : Ch16 : Telnet, TFTP, and xinetd](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch16_:_Telnet,_TFTP,_and_xinetd#TFTP)